# Binding to a System.Windows.Controls.Frame.Source property

Tags: wpf, mvvm

```
<Frame Source="{Binding Path=ViewModelPropertyUri}" />
```

Is it possible to databind the Source of a System.Windows.Controls.Frame to a property on my ViewModel?  From what I have tried so far I cannot make it work.  It doesn't seem as if the Source property is being updated whenever the ViewModelPropertyUri value changes.

I'm fairly new to WPF and MVVM in general, but I get the overall idea and have the bindings working in various other scenarios.

Thanks!

Comment: First thing you need to do is turn up debug messages for databinding: http://i.imgur.com/UAxJO.png Next, re-run and check the output window and see what errors are there.

Comment: @Will, thanks - I bet that is invaluable :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see nothing in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.frame.source.aspx) on that property to make me think that you wouldn't be able to bind to that property.

Are you sure the PropertyChanged event is being raised when ViewModelPropertyUri value changes?